# Why floating point does not start from negative numbers when it exceeds its range?

Tags: c, floating-point

As we all know when a integer varible exceeds its range it starts from other end that is from negative numbers.
 for example

```
int a=2147483648;
printf("%d",a);
```

**OUTPUT:** 
-2147483648 (as I was expecting)

Now I tried the same for floating points.
for example

```
float a=3.4e39;//as largest float is 3.4e38
printf("%f",a);
```

**OUTOUT:**
1.#INF00 (I was expecting some negative float value)
I didn't get the above output exactly but I know It represents positive infinity.
So my question is simply why it does not start from other end(negative values like integers)?

Comment: Integers and floating point numbers are stored differently in binary.  Also, either way, I'm sure this behavior is undefined, and shortly someone will be along with a link to a duplicate.

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined; there is no guarantee it will wrap to the negative range.

Comment: You should try what happens if you do `float a=3.4e38 +1e38`. The way youdo it, +INFinity is probably detection at compilation time.

Comment: Somehow, this question reminds me of: Why does my car not crow...

Comment: You need to use a crowbar with it.

Comment: Why should it? Wrapping around is a very strange artifact of how 2's complement binary arithmetic works if treated, as much as possible, as though it were unsigned binary.

Comment: @nhgrif I don't see any undefined behavior in either the integer or the floating-point example.

Comment: @ecatmur The overflow in a conversion from integer to integer, which is what happens in the snippet in the question, is implementation-defined. It is not undefined.

Comment: @ecatmur `INT_MAX + 1` result is not `INT_MIN` but is undefined behavior. But `int a=2147483648;` is not UB and as @PascalCuoq mentioned it is a implementation-defined integer conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floating point numbers are stored in a different format than integer numbers, and don't follow the same over-/under-flowing mechanics.

More specifically, the binary bit-pattern for `2147483648` is `1000000000000000` which in a [two's complement system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (like the one used on almost all modern computers) is the same as `-2147483648`.

Most computers today uses [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE754) format for floating point values, and those are handled quite differently from plain integers.

Comment: you mean negative floats are stored differently from positive ones 
Thats why it does not wrap to negative range?

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar It's still a single bit representing negative values, but I suggest you follow the link in my answer about the IEEE754 format.

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar I also suggest you read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar: Because that would be daft and it would complicate people's lives when they write numerical code.

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar: Floating point values are stored differently than integers. (Signed) integers are usually stored in two's complement, which is what causes the overflow into negative. IEEE-754 floating point values are stored as unsigned significand and an extra sign bit, so there, overflow of that significand does not result in negative numbers. It merely causes an increment in the exponent, when that is possible. Now, some special values, like denormals, the infinities or NaNs follow even different rules.

Comment: FWIW, the bit pattern for 2147483648 is binary `10000000000000000000000000000000`, i.e. a 32 bit number, not a 16 bit number. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In IEEE-754, the maximum finite `float` (binary-32) value is below `double` value `3.4e39`.

IEEE-754 says (for default rounding-direction attribute roundTiesToEven):

> (IEEE-754:2008, 4.3.1 Rounding-direction attributes to nearest) "In the following two rounding-direction attributes, an infinitely precise result with magnitude at least
>   b emax (b − ½ b 1−p) shall round to ∞ with no change in sign; here emax and p are determined by the destination format (see 3.3)"

So in this declaration:

```
float a=3.4e39;
```

the conversion yields a positive infinity.

Comment: Why are you citing the part of the clause that applies when the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, when the target type can represent +inf and -inf, and the range of values that can be represented is thus anything between them?

Comment: @PascalCuoq agree, the quote to C Standard is not relevant as infinite are available in IEEE-754, I remove it.

Answer (score 3):

Under IEEE floating point, it's impossible for arithmetic to overflow because the representable range is `[-INF,INF]` (including the endpoints). As usual, floating point is subject to rounding when the exact value is not representable, and in your case, rounding yields `INF`.

Comment: To make this question more fun to answer coherently, note that IEEE talks about "overflow" in a bunch of places.

Comment: Overflow in IEEE floating point sense has a very different meaning from overflow in the C sense. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have looked at floating point. This answer is about why signed integer values traditionally wrap around. It is not because that is particularly nice behavior. It is because that is what is expected because it is the way it has been done for a long time.

Especially in early hardware, with either discrete logic or very limited chip space, there was a major advantage to using the same adder for signed and unsigned integer addition and subtraction.

Floating point arithmetic was done in software except on special "scientific" computers that cost extra. Floating point numbers are always signed, and, as has been pointed out in other answers, have their own format. There is no signed/unsigned hardware sharing issue.

Common hardware for signed and unsigned integers can be achieved by using [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation for signed integer types.

What follows is based on 8 bit integers, with each bit pattern represented as 2 hexadecimal digits. Other widths work the same way.

00 through 7f have the same meaning in unsigned and 2's complement, 0 through 127 in that order, the intersection of the two ranges. 80 through ff represent 128 through 255, in that order, for unsigned integers, but represent negative numbers for signed. To make addition the same for both, 80 represents -128, and ff represents -1.

Now see what happens if you add 1 to 7f. For unsigned, it has to increment from 127 to 128. That means the resulting bit pattern is 80, which is also the most negative signed value. The price of sharing an adder is wrap-around at one point in the range.